# Partial migration from SVN

Tags: mercurial

In terms of learning Mercurial and migration from SVN to it I have couple questions:

1. if we decide to move to mercurial just one project and continue to use SVN for other projects but we really need to copy release branches and trunk to old SVN repository - is it easy thing?
2. SVN uses LDAP authentication - can mercurial use it too?
3. We use php and have own created deployer software which deploys branch to production and it means we have in SVN production property files, but mercurial commits all changes in directory - what is common way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. HGSubversion solve most of problems for transparent SVN-usage from Mercurial, except linearization of history (before push to SVN) for non-linear work in Mercurial. It's (linearization) handwork with (some) extensions, nothing impossible
2. For Apache as  frontend, which can use LDAP-auth it's as easy as write

> AuthType basic
>
> AuthBasicProvider ldap
>
> AuthName "Mercurial Repositories"
>
> AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost:389/ou=People,dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)
>
> Require valid-user

1. Call hg-commands from your php-code?

Comment: Thanks for reply. #3 - I mean developers should have locally modified config files which are located in project folder(repository) and these files shouldn't be commit by default because it will break production environment.

Comment: if nobody must commit this files - add pattern to hgirnore. If files must be in repo, but in some "common" form - store base, identical for all, in repo, and every dev support own local variation using MQ extension or localbranches extension (I like MQ more for flexibility)

Comment: We add file to repo, then add them to hgirnore, and when we need changes we use MQ to set new content in these files, right?

Comment: MQ **OR** hgignore are two ***different** policies. Or ignore file totally (hgignore without commit to repo) or commit base and local changes save in MQ. Not both at the same time